# Is $(Q,.)$ an abelian and cyclic group?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups

My teacher said that an example of an abelian group that is not cyclic is $(Q/\{0\},.)$.

So I was curious why did he use $Q/\{0\}$ instead of just $Q$. Does using $Q$ make it cyclic?

Comment: $(\mathbb Q,\cdot)$ is not a group, just a monoid, since $0$ isn't invertible.

Comment: Although the rationals under addition would also have been an example of a non-cyclic abelian group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out, $\Bbb Q \color{red}{\setminus} \{0\}$ was used since $(\Bbb Q, \cdot)$ is not a group because $0$ has no multiplicative inverse.

$(\Bbb Q \color{red}{\setminus} \{0\}, \cdot)$ is indeed abelian since the usual multiplication of rationals is commutative. However, it is not cyclic.
To see this, suppose that $r \in \Bbb Q \color{red}{\setminus} \{0\}$ was a generator. Then, $r^n = 2$ and $r^m = 3$ for some integers $n$ and $m$.
By considering $2^m$ and $3^n$, arrive at a contradiction.

---

Note the slash that I have used. $\Bbb Q \color{red}{\setminus} \{0\}$ denotes the set of non-zero rationals. The slash which you have used has a different meaning.

Comment: Like you, I prefer $\setminus$ for set difference.  But I recognize $/$ when it is used for set difference.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Every group has exactly one idempotent, namely its identity. For suppose $x^2=x$ is an idempotent. Then $xx=x^2=x=ex$, so multiplying on the right by $x^{-1}$ gives $x=e$.

In $(\Bbb Q,\cdot)$ both $0\cdot 0=0$ and $1\cdot 1=1$ but $0\neq 1$. Hence $(\Bbb Q,\cdot)$ is not a group.

---

An example of an abelian group that is not cyclic is the [Klein four group](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_four-group).